# Law of iterated expectations with two random variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, conditioning

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. I want to calculate $E[X|X<Y]$. I am wondering whether I can use the law of iterated expectations in order to calculate it, i.e. $E[E[X|X<Y,Y]]$. Do I threat $Y$ as a constant in the inner expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated.

The law of iterated expectations (LIE) will not help you here.

$E[X|X<Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^y x P(x,y)dx\right) dy$

$E[X|X,Y,Y]$ is simply the inner integral $\int_{-\infty}^y x P(x,y)dx$, so if you try to apply LIE the way you showed, you'll end up with the same integral, i.e. you'll get where you started from: $E[E[X|X<Y,Y]] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(E[X|X<Y,Y]\right) dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^y x P(x,y)dx\right) dy$

Comment: Could you give an explanation why it does not work, please?

Comment: How are you going to plug it here? Show me how did you get to the 2nd expression of yours from the original problem.

Comment: I did it because in the sample selection models (econometrics), we have something like $E[v_2|x,y_2] = E[v_2|x,v_2>-x\delta_2] = \lambda(x \delta_2)$ with $\lambda (\cdot) = \phi(\cdot)/\Phi(\cdot)$. Thus, I thought that  $E[v_2|y_2] = E[\lambda(x \delta_2)]$ and it should work in both directions. But I don't understand this point well, thus a good explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: It's difficult to understand where exactly you're struggling, because the example you gave in the comment is different from the case in your question. There's no jump from $E[v_2|y_2]$ to $E[v_2|x,y_2]$ for you to expect that there has to be the jump backwards. Because that's what you're trying to do in your question.

Comment: I thought about it, but still I don't understand. So, if I want to calculate $E[v_2|y_2=1] = E[E[v_2|y_2=1,x]] = E[E[v_2|x,v_2 > x \delta_2]]$. But is is the same what I have, isn't it?

Comment: Unless there's something that you implicitly assume about $v_2,y_2,x$ this is not generally true: $E[v_2|y_2=1]=E[E[v_2|y_2=1,x]]$. You added another condition, then average on it.

Comment: Then I am missing something. In general, I can apply the law of iterated expectations $E[X] = E_Y[E_{X|Y}[X|Y]]$ always. Is this case different because I have a conditional expectation in the very beginning?

Comment: I think I got it: do I have to have $E[v_2|y_2=1]=E[E[v_2|y_2=1,x]|y_2 = 1]$?